# Scheduled reminders and memberships

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

Looking for a quick answer from someone who may have done this before I spend hours of testing.

I am implementing a "Family" membership where members of family will get the inherited membership of the paying member based on a relationship that I created. This works really well. The paying member shows a membership "Family". The members of the family show a membership "Family (by relationship)".

I want to schedule a reminder for the paying member to renew their family membership, but don't want to send the reminder to the members of the family (some of them are children and while they may have email addresses entered into their record, they shouldn't get emails for membership renewals).

So... if I create a scheduled reminder based on the Family membership, will the (by relationship) members get the reminder?

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.47 on WordPress 4.9.5

Comment: This is a great question. Were you able to get a solution that worked? If so, it would be really helpful if you could share that here by posting an answer. Given that CiviCRM provides the household contact type out of the box, using that to handle memberships effectively for a family seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the "Limiting or adding to your recipient" setting and use a smart group to only include primary members or some fairly complicated smart group that pulls only those that are paying members

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#limiting-or-adding-to-your-recipient-list